# Do enums have storage space when they're not instantiated?

Tags: c++, c, enums, macros, c-preprocessor

If I don't instantiate an enum, and just have:

enum myEnum {val1 = 0, val2, val3};

I'm wondering if all the compiler will do is go through all your code and replace val1, val2 etc. with the corresponding numbers. Meaning it wouldn't create storage for it in your finished program.  Actually the final result would be constant values substituted wherever you wrote val1, val2 etc.?

I'm not sure if "instantiate" is the right word. Also, when I say it goes through your code and replaces stuff, I'm not saying it pastes it in like with macro replacement at the preprocessor stage. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enumerators of an enumeration are prvalues, so when you use `val1` in the source code, it is similar to typing out a literal such as `42`; you do not get a glvalue (which would refer to a location in memory where the actual value is stored). It wouldn't make any sense for the compiler to reserve space in the program for the enumerators since those memory locations would never be accessed according to the rules of the language.

Then again, are you really so short on memory that this matters?

Comment: The enumerators of an enumeration are, OK, so what are the instantiations? When you go myEnum enum1; enum1 is stored and holds a value. Really it's no different to the type in the enum brackets? So maybe an int? And every time you refer to enum1 it's just another name for what the program keeps in memory as an int?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice Just as a side note, remember that scoped enums can have an underlying type that is not an `int`.

Comment: @skypjack Thanks. I've just found out I don't need to give it a name either, so I made it as enum : bool{ SEPARABLE = true, NONSEPARABLE = false};  Is it just c++ that has a billion and one ways of doing stuff? Seems quite ridiculous.  Often I find myself just typing in random stuff and find out that it's valid.

Comment: What are "prvalues" and "glvalues"? I know about rvalues and lvalues but have never heard about these.

Answer (score 1):

The standard describes an enumeration as:

> [...] a distinct type with named constants.

Therefore yes - *final result would be constant values substituted wherever you wrote val1, val2 etc*.